# No me toma el juego de caracteres UTF-8 al ejecutar

Tags: java, utf-8

Tengo la siguiente porción de código que me genera la única salida por terminal en los test que estoy ejecutando:

```java
throw new Exception("No hay contenido en la posición "
   + --index + " del patrón: " + pattern);
```

La cual me da lo siguiente:

```java
java.lang.Exception: No hay contenido en la posici??n 8 del patr??n: 10((100)()(1))
```

Como pueden ver las únicas dos letras con tildes son cambiadas por los símbolos `??`.

Actualmente se está corriendo con `java 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS` desde `bash 5.2.12(1)-release` en `Windows Terminal 1.16.10262.0`.

Comment: Hola Isaac, vamos por partes, el error es que no encuentra lo que busca en la ruta especificada, por otro lado, el programa y/o sistema operativo, no está configurado para leer determinados caracteres (solo afecta lo que tu ves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser algo propio de la versión de java ya que al desinstalar la versión 17 e instalar la versión `18.0.2.1 2022-08-18` me tomo el juego de caracteres correctamente.